# Can't Import Python3 Requests Module

Tags: python-3.x

I am using VS Code using Python 3.9.1.

I have setup a venv called `env`. Folder structure is:

```
env
  - Include
  - Lib
      - requests
  - Scripts
  - pyvenv.cfg
  - scrape.py
```

In my script, `scrape.py` I have:

```
import requests

URL = "https://etherscan.io/token/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d"
page = requests.get(URL)

print(page.text)
```

I get the following error:
`Import "requests" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMIssingModuleSource)`

I have installed requests as you can see from the directory structure. A `pip list` gives the following which also shows requests is installed:

[image]

Comment: Did you restart vs code sometimes when installing something new happens this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command **select python interpreter**, setting it to your venv.

[Make sure you Activate](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-and-use-packages) your venv in the console.

I think it'll add the string `(venv)` to your prompt. After running activate, `pip` and `python` now

There's additional guides here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments

Comment: well done, this worked.  I had to select my venv from the ctrl + shift + p menu